# Web Bluetooth API - Why I can't detect mobile Bluetooth

Tags: javascript, html, bluetooth

I am trying to connect my web site to my phone Bluetooth but every time I scan Bluetooth devices any phone Bluetooth is not on the list it means web Bluetooth API can't detect phone Bluetooth. How can I solve it?

Comment: What bluetooth profile are you trying to use?

Comment: any profile that support mobile phone. my current bluetooth profile is A2DP

Comment: So, you want to connect between your phone and what?  In any case, Web Bluetooth API isn't appropriate for using A2DP, as far as I know.  Use the regular system utilities for that.